# Using a PHP web-crawler to find certain words without certain elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm following http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for making web-crawler using php, but im so confuse how to search for words without specifying an element. So word search is done based on all available data.
because the problem here is that now I am specifying the data being searched using the `<p>` element but when there is no element `<p>` the result is empty.

this is my code

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html('https://adityadees.blogspot.com/');

foreach($html->find('<p>') as $element) 
if (strpos($element, 'yang') !== false) {
    echo $element;
} else {
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

for example I want to try searching for words that contain 'yang' but, the results are empty because these words don't contain the < p> element.
[image]

my results
[image]

but if the word is contained in the < p> element, the result goes well.
[image]

im tryng to change this line

```
foreach($html->find('<p>') as $element)
```

to

```
foreach($html->find() as $element)
```

but i got errors like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function simple_html_dom::find(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\index.php on line 5 and at least 1 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\simple_html_dom.php:1975 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\index.php(5): simple_html_dom->find() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\simple_html_dom.php on line 1975

Comment: So, the input is the webpage and a word, output should be to ONLY TELL if that word exists in a webpage?

Comment: the expected results are the same as @user11222393 except that without specifying certain elements, in other words the input is the entire webpage. because maybe the word is in the footer or in another part.

Comment: If you got that word, why would you like to show the entire paragraph? Your question title gives me an intention to just check if that word exists in a web page or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to find all paragraphs/text that contains your given word?

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://adityadees.blogspot.com/');

$strings_array = array();

//it searches for any (*) tag with text yang in it
foreach($html->find('*[plaintext*=yang]') as $element) {
    //take only elements which doesn't have childnodes, so are last ones in recursion 
    if ($element->firstChild() == null) {
        //there still are duplicate strings so add only unique values to an array
        if (!in_array($element->innertext, $strings_array)) {
            $strings_array[] = $element->innertext;

        }
    } 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($strings_array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

It isn't final solution, but something to start with.
At least it finds word yang 61 times - same as in html source of given page.

Comment: but why this dont work for other page? i try change url to https://adityadees.blogspot.com/2019/01/melihat-rangking-website.html

Comment: What is the result? It works for me. It finds 9 strings with 12 yang words in it. In source there are 13, because one is in meta tag

Comment: ok this works, I'm sorry I don't see if you eliminate data redundancy so I miscalculated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach($html->find('<body>') as $element) 
if (strpos($element, 'yang') !== false) {
    echo $element;
} else {
    echo $element;
}
```

Comment: using that code, the result does not display search results.

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting source of given page you can see that post summary is inside div tag with class = item-snippet.

```
<div class='item-snippet'> Bagaimana Cara Mengganti Akun Mobile Legend ?  itulah yang selalu dipertanyakan oleh orang yang baru memulai bermain game Mobile Legend.  S...</div>
```

You can get your result if you search for your word in such div's:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://adityadees.blogspot.com/');

foreach($html->find('div[class=item-snippet]') as $element) {

    if (strpos($element, 'yang') !== false) {

        echo $element;

    } 

}
```

result:

```
Bagaimana Cara Mengganti Akun Mobile Legend ? itulah yang selalu dipertanyakan oleh orang yang baru memulai bermain game Mobile Legend. S...
Bagaimana Cara Mengaitkan Akun Mobile Legend di Patch Baru ? Mungkin masih ada yang bingung tentang cara mengaitkan akun mobile legend den...
Kali ini kita akan membahas tentang bagaimana cara menghitung luas persegi panjangan dengan PHP Hal yang pertama dilakukan adalah membuat ...
```

Is this you are looking for?

Comment: yes the results I expected were like that, but without specifying certain parts of the element. imagine like using ctrl + f to find the word part. in other words search for words on all web pages.